# Laravel 5.4 error on Heroku deployment

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-5.4

I deployed my Laravel 5.4 project to Heroku, but I keep getting this error

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Session\Store::getToken()
```

I edited the `HtmlServiceProvider.php` in `vendor\laravelcollective\html\src\HtmlServiceProvider.php` then pushed to `heroku master`, but it seems that the `vendor` folder I have is not pushed to `heroku`. Is there any solution to these?

Answer (score 0):

try going for force push, it will replaced all the files
OR
checked if try checking in your .gitignore file if the folder is being ignored

Ex.
git push heroku master -f